# Using Ajax Jquery to delete an Item in Zend

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I want to delete a row of user table when I press a delete button. But it's error

code in deleteAction

```
public function deleteAction(){
    $this->view->Title = 'Member :: Group manager :: Delete';
    $this->view->headTitle($this->view->Title,true);
    $tblGroup = new Default_Model_UserGroup();
    $tblGroup->deleteItem($this->_arrParam,array('task'=>'admin-delete'));
    $this->_redirect($this->_actionMain);
}
```

code in file jquery

```
    function DeleteGroup(element,id) {
jConfirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Group?', 'Delete Group', function(r) { if (r)
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "<?= $this->baseUrl($this->currentController. '/delete/id')?>" + id,
  data: '',
  success: function(response){
    $(element).parents('tr').remove();
    $.jGrowl('Group deleted');
  }
});
});
}
```

link

```
<a href="#" onclick="DeleteGroup(this,21)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
```

Comment: First, what's the error? Second, you've posted your `editAction` method. You probably want to show us `deleteAction`?

Comment: I've revised editAction. What's the error? it doesn't work when I on the link

Comment: Check your browser's console. Do you get any error regarding your request.

Comment: It notify: Uncaught ReferenceError: jConfirm is not defined

Comment: Have you attached any javascript file regarding jConfirm? if not than do it. and use small 'c' in `jconfirm`.